# Probability, How do you calculate dice probability with combinations?

Tags: probability

Linking image of the dice.

https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/imperial-assault/images/d/d7/Imperial_Assault_Die_Face.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/300?cb=20150825022932

If i roll 1 yellow dice, 1 blue and 1 green. I need 3 lightning.

Yellow ³⁄₆ chance 1 lightning and ⅙ chance 2.

Blue ²⁄₆  chance 1.

Green ³⁄₆ chance 1.

How do i calculate odds of getting 3 or more lighting?

I know i can calculate ²⁄₆ * ³⁄₆ * ⁴⁄₆ = 1/9 but i am sure this does not take into account combinations. For example getting 2 lightings on yellow, would only need 1 on blue,green or both for a total of 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can seperate them to cases. By addition rule, probability of two non-mutually exclusive events is
$$P(X + Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X Y)$$

X+Y means X or Y occurred, XY means X and Y both occurred.

Your case 1 is get 1 lightning with 3/6 probability,
probability to get at least 3 lightning is  $3/6 * 2/6 * 3/6 = 1/12 $.

Case 2 is get 2 lightning with 1/6 probability,
probability to get at least 3 lightning is  $ 1/6 * (2/6 + 3/6 - 2/6*3/6 ) = 1/9 $.

Hence the total probability is $1/12+1/9=7/36$

I skiped some analysis on problem you can ask if you need explanation.

Comment: I'm getting $\frac{11}{36}$.

Comment: @ploosu2 p2 = 1/6. you will get 7/36 after fixing it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and explanation. To verify i understand correctly, i am adding 1 green dice as the game allows, and using your calculation. 

3/6∗2/6∗3/6∗3/6 = ¹⁄₂₄

1/6∗(2/6+3/6+3/6−2/6∗3/6∗3/6) = 270/1296

270/1296 + 54/1296 = 324/1296 = 1/4?

Comment: Also thinking about it? How does your formula decide i only need 3 surges, for example lets say i roll 50 blue with 2/6 chance. My chance should getting 3 surges should be close to 100% with that many rolls.

Comment: Lol sorry 1 last question, why do we subtract if X+Y from XY.
If i understand your formula X+Y should only represent green or blue getting lighting but not both at the same time. And XY should only represent green and blue getting lightning same time. So all outcome should be valid if they are not repeat chances.
1/6∗(2/6+3/6−2/6∗3/6)=1/9.

Comment: @user3538292 for 3 event, use inclusion-exclusion principle $$P(X+Y+Z) = \Sigma P(X) - \Sigma P(XY) + P(XYZ) $$, I use $\Sigma$ means you need to sum up all possibilities .

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle check the image in wiki to help you understand what is going on

Comment: You asked why we need the consequences terms (they are substracting and adding alternatively in higher case), they are just repeatedly removing the overlapped part.

Comment: For the other question, if you want to count chance of getting 3 surges with 50 blue rolls. It will be faster to calculate the failing cases (0,1,2) and substract the chance from 1. (success chance + fail chance = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y, B, G$ be the number of lightnings in the respective dice throws. We want to calculate $\mathbb{P}(Y+B+G \geq 3)$. It's a convolution!

- $Y: p_0=\frac{2}{6}, \space p_1=\frac{3}{6}, \space p_2=\frac{1}{6}$
- $B: p_0=\frac{4}{6}, \space p_1=\frac{2}{6}$
- $G: p_0=\frac{3}{6}, \space p_1=\frac{3}{6}$

First calculate the distribution of $Y+B$:

$$ 
\mathbb{P}(Y+B = 0) = \frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{6} = \frac{8}{36} \\
\mathbb{P}(Y+B = 1) = \frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{2}{6} + \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{6} = \frac{16}{36} \\
\mathbb{P}(Y+B = 2) = \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{2}{6} + \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{6} = \frac{10}{36} \\
\mathbb{P}(Y+B = 3) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{2}{6} = \frac{2}{36}
$$

Then
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y+B + G = 3) = \frac{10}{36} \cdot \frac{3}{6} + \frac{2}{36} \cdot \frac{3}{6}  = \frac{1}{6} \\
\mathbb{P}(Y+B + G = 4) = \frac{2}{36} \cdot \frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{36} \\
$$

So
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y+B + G \geq 3) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{36} = \frac{7}{36}.
$$